# jQuery validation logic fails when last element is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a scenario when I have 3 dropdowns and need to implement two validations over them but as a group.

1) Out of 3, 2 dropdowns should have value other than "No". This is similar to required validation. Instead of check for blank will check for "No".

2) No 2 dropdowns can have same value.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqadLgd/1/)

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
  var numberRequired = options[0];
  var selector = options[1];
  var fields = $(selector, element.form);
  var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
    // it's more clear to compare with empty string
    return $(this).val() != "No"; 
  });
  var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);

  // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
  if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired){ //&& empty_fields[0] == element) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
// {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));

jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualToGroup", function(value, element, options) {
var numberRequired = options[0];
var selector = options[1];
// get all the elements passed here with the same class
var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(selector).not(element);
// the value of the current element
var valueToCompare = value;
// count
var matchesFound = 0;
// loop each element and compare its value with the current value
// and increase the count every time we find one
jQuery.each(elems, function(){
    thisVal = $(this).val();
    if(thisVal == valueToCompare){
            matchesFound++;
        }
});

  if (matchesFound >= numberRequired){ //&& elems[0] != element) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
}, jQuery.format("No two fields can have same value."));
```

One of the scenarios has failed i.e. when select1 and select2 are not "No" but still have same value no msg is displayed.

Can someone please suggest whats missing. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a 7-year-old version of jQuery Validate?!   Many bugs have been fixed within `require_from_group` since then.   Please upgrade to version 1.15.0 and refactor your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upgrade the plugin from the nearly 7-year-old version 1.7 to [the latest which is 1.15](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js).
2. Replace the outdated version of `require_from_group` with the latest one from [version 1.15](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).
3. Replace `jQuery.format("No two fields can have same value.")` with `$.validator.format("No two...`

You'll find that this updated version works a bit more predictably.

---

**EDIT**:

You also need a complete rewrite on your `notEqualToGroup` rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqualToGroup", function(value, element, options) {

    var isvalid = true,
        values = [],
        temp = [];

    // put all values into an array 
    $(options).each(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });

    // check array for duplicates
    $.each(values, function(key, val) {
        if ($.inArray(val, temp) === -1) {
            temp.push(val);
        } else {
            isvalid = false; // duplicate found
        }
    });

    return isvalid;
}, $.validator.format("No two fields can have same value."));
```

Essentially, put all three values into an array and check for duplicates.

```
....
select1: {
    require_from_group: [2, ".at_least_one"],
    notEqualToGroup: ".at_least_one"
},
....
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/nu4dcstv/](http://jsfiddle.net/nu4dcstv/)

Comment: thanks @sparky, actually I am actually using 1.11 version but some how I took one of my old samples and forked it. here is the update link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqadLgd/4/). **require_from_group** method was working ok but I am unable to design **notEqualToGroup**. All I want is current element value to be validated with with other group element values and if match found then validation fails.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqadLgd/6/) I think i fixed the stop script issue but the validation runs immediately and does not wait for the button to be pressed. Also the case where last element of the group is valid does not generate any msg stands still. hope m clear in making my point.

Comment: @NikhilGupta, set `onfocusout: false` and `onclick: false` if you only want to trigger validation when you try to submit.   Seems to work for me:  "NO, NO, YES" triggers an error:  http://jsfiddle.net/uaqadLgd/7/

Comment: "No No Yes" triggers a "require_from_group" validation error but "Yes Yes No" should also trigger a "notEqualToGroup" validation error. Which is not happening. I mean no message is coming.

Comment: @NikhilGupta, the message is blank because all three field messages are not the same in this case.  [Remove the `groups` option and you can clearly see this.](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqadLgd/8/)  In other words, you'll need to figure out why your custom rule is failing to flag the third field.

Comment: thanks sparky, now only one rule solved both the purposes -http://jsfiddle.net/nu4dcstv/1/